# Wide variety of results in Breusch-Pagan Tests on simulated data?

Tags: heteroscedasticity, lagrange-multipliers

I wanted to see how the results of the BP-test would come out. This stemmed from a debate with someone who claimed that the BP-test would start rejecting the null hypothesis of homoskedasticity even though the variance wasn't heteroskedastic. Now, I believe I proved theoretically that the BP-test should not reject for large sample sizes but I wanted to test it in an experimental fashion. What I found is that it is not dependent on sample size (the results were similar for all sample sizes) but what struck me as odd was the immense variety in the results from data sampled from the same distributions. See code:

```
plot(x=1,y=0.6357275,xlim=c(0,100),ylim=c(0,1),ylab="P-Value",xlab="BP-Test Number",main="Plot BP-Test P-Values for Regression w/ e~N and N=100")
for(i in 2:100)
{
  x = runif(100,min=0,max=1000)

  y = x + rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=1)

  linearModel = lm(y~x)
  points(x=i,y=bptest(linearModel)$p.value)
}
```

The first plot is just a result I got before running the loop. Does anyone know why the variability is so great?
 [image]